# Finding certain files on system and executing a command in parent directory bash

Tags: bash, shell, find, exec, cd

I need to find all directories containing a file named "thisfile".
Once the files are found I need to perform a certain command in each directory containing the files.
For example: find the directories containing "thisfile" and list all files contained in each directory.
I'm trying: `find . -name "thisfile"`, then I was thinking about cd into each folder and perform the commands but I'm not able to achieve this.
For example something like `find . -name "thisfile" -exec dirname && cd into those folders && ls"`

Comment: With your approach, the shell would already break your command into 3 separated commands at the `&&`, because `&&` is a statement separator. `find` should complain that the terminator for the `-exec` is missing.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `-execdir` :

```
find . -name "thisfile" -execdir ls \;
```